# Kusto :: find all SQL Server and the number of databases within each one

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer, azure-resource-graph

I need to find a list of SQL Servers that are good candidates for SQL Elastic Pool.

I have this Kusto query but it just list all the databases once:

```
resources
| where type == 'microsoft.sql/servers/databases'
| summarize TotalDatabases = count() by name
```

From my understanding I should maybe join:

- | where type == 'microsoft.sql/servers/databases'
- | where type == 'microsoft.sql/servers'

Any idea how to do it?

The result should look like this:

| serverName | NumberOfDatabases |
| --- | --- |
| Server1 | 16 |
| Server2 | 3 |
| Server3 | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can get the list of Server Name and Database Name by using the below Kusto query**

```
resources
| where type == 'microsoft.sql/servers/databases'
| summarize NumberOfDatabases = count() by ServerName = tolower(split(id, '/')[8])
| project ServerName, NumberOfDatabases
```

**Output**-

[image]

Comment: Odd, that returns me 1 server name with 1 database. Where are all the other servers?

Comment: Modified my answer and query, refer the updated answer

Comment: Crazy good! Thank you so much